# Heron template toolbar problem

Tags: geoext, openlayers-2, heron-mapping-client

A couple of days ago, I went to this site [heron-mc.org/examples](http://heron-mc.org/examples).html and found some useful application templates. I viewed them, went to view source code and copied the source code to my editor to make it my code. So far the code is displaying the map and a couple of features but some aren't working as they are supposed to like on the web template. To be specific, the toolbar is working fine but I can't see the button's description(icon and text) and the sliding zoom is not complete. I'm asking for an advice on how to go about fixing my problem. I have also attached a picture of the output.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Images are accessed externally, therefore one has to create their own storage locally with picture so that they can be easily accessed.

Comment: In your question example, you have a local service (accessed through file://C:/... ) so having externally available files shouldn't necessarily have been the solution.  Could you expand on the solution, did you just need to make the image URL's  relative for example.  Can you show the location where the image URL's are modified